# How to call python function with arguments from C# and get a return value

Tags: python, c#, arrays, function, arguments

Hello I am trying to call below python function "mclp" from C#

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
from gurobipy import *
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
from numpy import random

def generate_candidate_sites(points,M=100):
    hull = ConvexHull(points)
    polygon_points = points[hull.vertices]
    poly = Polygon(polygon_points)
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds
    sites = []
    while len(sites) < M:
        random_point = Point([random.uniform(min_x, max_x),
                             random.uniform(min_y, max_y)])
        if (random_point.within(poly)):
            sites.append(random_point)
    return np.array([(p.x,p.y) for p in sites])

def mclp(points,K,radius,M):
    import time
    start = time.time()
    sites = generate_candidate_sites(points,M)
    J = sites.shape[0]
    I = points.shape[0]
    D = distance_matrix(points,sites)
    mask1 = D<=radius
    D[mask1]=1
    D[~mask1]=0
    # Build model
    m = Model()
    # Add variables
    x = {}
    y = {}
    for i in range(I):
      y[i] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y%d" % i)
    for j in range(J):
      x[j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%d" % j)

    m.update()
    # Add constraints
    m.addConstr(quicksum(x[j] for j in range(J)) == K)

    for i in range(I):
        m.addConstr(quicksum(x[j] for j in np.where(D[i]==1)[0]) >= y[i])

    m.setObjective(quicksum(y[i]for i in range(I)),GRB.MAXIMIZE)
    m.setParam('OutputFlag', 0)
    m.optimize()
    end = time.time()
   
    solution = []
    if m.status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
        for v in m.getVars():
            # print v.varName,v.x
            if v.x==1 and v.varName[0]=="x":
               solution.append(int(v.varName[1:]))
    opt_sites = sites[solution]
    return opt_sites
```

The input arguments are

```
K = 20
radius = 0.2
M = 100
points =[[ 1.85737721  0.3341904 ]
 [-0.93679108  0.3511183 ]
 [ 0.68220641  0.84082034]
 [-0.88955891  0.84335212]
 [ 1.83264259 -0.15681283]
 [ 1.2737921  -0.04591726]
 [ 0.12594991  0.93641684]
 [ 0.15216603  0.75590733]
 [ 0.93954871 -0.61432142]
 [ 0.44905661 -0.39367967]]
```

From C# I want to call this function as "opt_sites= mclp(points,K,radius,M)"

'points' and 'opt_sites' are similar arrays. I tried Ironpython, but I cannot install numpy or gurobipy  in it. So I believe the ideal method will be to use a direct process calling method from C#. I am confused how to pass the "points" argument which is an array.

Currently my c# code looks like this

```
string python = @"C:\Users\MSI\anaconda3\python.exe";
string myPythonApp = @"C:\Users\MSI\Documents\Work\Development\mclp.py";
ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp + " " + x + " " + y;`
```

I am confused how to pass the points array into python.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to serialize your inputs into a json and then load that json in python into a dictionary. Also, it looks like you want to parse the output from standard output, so the result of `mclp` is just printed.

Adding this to the bottom of your python script:

```py
# Can be imported at the top with the rest of the imports
import sys
import json

def main():
    # Assuming the first argument passed to the script is the path to the json
    # Can also be changed to hardcoded file path
    json_path = sys.argv[1]

    with open(json_path) as fs:
        input_data = json.load(fs)

    points = np.asarray(input_data["points"])
    result = mclp(points, input_data["K"], input_data["radius"], input_data["M"])
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The sample command line command would be: `python mcpl.py my_input_file.json`